# Showing that the symmetric Beta distribution is normal by Slutsky's Theorem?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, asymptotics, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose that $B_n \sim B(n,n)$, then I would like to show that as $n \to \infty$, $2\sqrt{2n}(B_n-\frac{1}{2}) \to N(0,1)$.

I know that the Beta distribution can be written as the following Gamma form:

$$
B_n = \frac{G_n}{G_n + G'_n}
$$

Where $G_n$ is a Gamma distribution with shape parameter $n$ and scale parameter $1$, and $G'_n$ is a Gamma distribution with shape parameter $n$ and scale parameter $1$ **independent** of $G_n$.

Now, the Gamma in turn can be rewritten as the sum of Exponential distribution with scale $1$.

So,

$$
G_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i 
$$

where $X_i \sim Expo(1)$ which are iid of each other and that

$$
G'_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X'_i 
$$

where $X'_i \sim Expo(1)$ are iid of each other as well.

Hence,

$$
B_n = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i }{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i  + \sum_{i=1}^n X'_i } = \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i  + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X'_i } 
$$

Now, by the Central Limit Theorem and Delta Method, the numerator has the distribution representation:

$$
\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - 1 \right) \overset{D}\to N\left(0,1\right)
$$

and that the bottom, by Law of Large Numbers, has that:

$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \overset{P}\to 1 \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X'_i \overset{P}\to 1
$$

Then,

$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i  + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X'_i  \overset{P}\to 2
$$

But because convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution, we have that

$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i  + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X'_i  \overset{D}\to 2
$$

Now, by Slutsky's theorem,

we have that

$$
\sqrt{4n}\left(B_n - \frac{1}{2}\right) = N\left(0,1\right)
$$

HOWEVER, it is my understanding that the symmetric Beta distribution converges towards $\sqrt{8n}\left(B_n - \frac{1}{2}\right) = N\left(0,1\right)$.

I am off by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$, what did I do wrong here?

Comment: The trouble with the current, modified, version of your solution is that you nowhere compute $\sqrt{n}(B_n-\frac12)$ in terms of the $X$s and $X'$s. As a result, the way you apply the CLT (no delta method here) to the numerator is unclear, and this is where the error creeps in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your solution is that

$$ \sqrt{n}\bigg( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k - \frac{1}{2} \bigg) \not\Rightarrow \mathcal{N}(0, 1). $$

A correct application of CLT will tell you that

$$ \sqrt{n}\bigg( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k - \color{red}{\boxed{1}} \bigg) \Rightarrow \mathcal{N}(0, 1) $$

Now let us utilize CLT and Slutsky's theorem to prove the convergence. Indeed, using your realization of $B_n$, we can write

$$
\sqrt{8n} \big( B_n - \tfrac{1}{2} \big)
= \sqrt{2n} \cdot \frac{G_n - G'_n}{G_n + G'_n}
= \frac{2}{\frac{1}{n}(G_n + G'_n)} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}} \sum_{k=1}^{n} (X_k - X'_k).
$$

On the one hand, WLLN tells you that

$$ \frac{1}{n}(G_n + G'_n) \stackrel{p}{\to} 2.$$

On the other hand, CLT tells you that

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}} \sum_{k=1}^{n} (X_k - X'_k) \Rightarrow \mathcal{N}(0, 1). $$

Therefore by Slutsky's theorem you can conclude that $\sqrt{8n}(B_n - \frac{1}{2}) \Rightarrow \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$.

---

**Addendum.** The issue in your original argument was that both the numerator and the denominator of $B_n$ contribute to the fluctuation and that you ignored the contribution from the denominator. To make things work (at least heuristically), let us write

$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k = 1 + \Delta \bar{X}
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} X'_k = 1 + \Delta \bar{X}'.$$

We know that $\Delta \bar{X}$ and $\Delta \bar{X}'$ are small quantities, so we can use Taylor expansion to approximate $B_n$ as follows:

$$ B_n = \frac{1 + \Delta \bar{X}}{2 + \Delta \bar{X} + \Delta \bar{X}'} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\Delta \bar{X}}{4} - \frac{\Delta \bar{X}}{4} + \text{[higher order terms]}$$

Since both $\Delta \bar{X}$ and $\Delta \bar{X}'$ are independent and have asymptotic distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, \frac{1}{n})$, this gives

$$ B_n \approx \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4}\mathcal{N}\bigg(0, \frac{2}{n}\bigg) = \mathcal{N}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{8n} \bigg). $$

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've corrected some things in the post, I am trying to actually show that $2\sqrt{2n}(B_n-\frac{1}{2}) \to N(0,1)$, but I am off by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$. Do you have any idea how I might get the final form of $2\sqrt{2n}(B_n-\frac{1}{2}) \to N(0,1)$? Thanks!

Comment: @user321627 I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I changed the $\frac{1}{2}$ to $1$, my apologies but I am not totally clear why my approach above doesn't work by using (by abusing notation a bit) $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i^{n}X_i \sim N(1, \frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i^{n}X_i + \frac{1}{n}\sum_i^{n}X'_i  \overset{p}\to 2$. Is it my abusing of notation that screws up the above? Thank you!