# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{2n-1}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}\int_{0}^{ \frac{x}{2\sqrt{2n+1}} + 1/2 } t^{n-1}(1 - t)^{n-1}dt $

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, probability-theory

> Prove that $
> \text{lim}_{n \to \infty}  \frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{2n - 1}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}\int_{0}^{ \frac{x}{2\sqrt{2n+1}} + 1/2 } t^{n-1}(1 - t)^{n-1}dt = \int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-y^2/2}dy.
> $

**Context:** This limit/integral appears in a problem about Convergence in Distribution of a random variable. We want to show that if $X_n \sim \text{Beta}(n, n)$ then

$$ Y_n = \frac{X_n - E(X_n)}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(X_n)}} \longrightarrow Z $$

where $Z \sim N(0, 1)$.

Comment: I believe your result can be shown without any heavy computation. This stems from the observation that $X_n$ is equal in distribution to a sum of $n$ (slightly dependent) random variables $Y_{n,1}, \dotsc, Y_{n,n}$ each with distribution $\mathrm{Beta}(1, 2n-1)$, then an application of a central limit theorem for the triangular array $(Y_{n,k})_{n \geq 1, 1 \leq k \leq n}$.

Comment: Would you elaborate? @nahp. I'm not sure how to do what you've said.

Comment: The statement about distributions comes from a fact about Beta random variables: we can write $$X_n = \frac{Y_1 + \dotsb + Y_1}{Y_1 + \dotsb + Y_n + Z_1 + \dotsb + Z_n}$$ where the $Y_1, \dotsc, Y_n, Z_1, \dotsc, Z_n$ are i.i.d. $\mathrm{Exp}(1)$. Then each term $$Y_{n,i} = \frac{Y_i}{Y_1 + \dotsb + Y_n + Z_1 + \dotsb + Z_n}$$ is $\mathrm{Beta}(1, 2n-1)$. However, I'm now realizing that it might be a bit tricky to get the result from a more general Central Limit Theorem. I was originally thinking of using the "Lyapunov CLT," but this requires that $Y_{n,1}, \dotsc, Y_{n,n}$ are independent.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I thought about Lindeberg's condition, then I thought the same: it requires independence.

Comment: If you want you can check my full work here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3845562/if-x-n-sim-textbetan-n-show-that-x-n-textex-n-sqrt-textvar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y^2/2}dy=\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y^2/2}dy+\int_0^x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y^2/2}dy=\frac 12+\frac 12\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

---

Now lets have a look at the LHS:
$$L(n)=\frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{2n-1}\sqrt{n}}}\int_0^{\frac{x}{2\sqrt{2n+1}}+\frac 12}t^{n-1}(1-t)^{n-1}dt=\frac{2^{2n-1}\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{\frac{x}{2\sqrt{2n+1}}+\frac 12}t^{n-1}(1-t)^{n-1}dt$$
if we look at the upper limit of our integral here:
$$\frac{x}{2\sqrt{2n+1}}+\frac12=\frac{x+\sqrt{2n+1}}{2\sqrt{2n+1}}$$
if we try letting $t=\frac{u}{2\sqrt{2n+1}}$ we get: $dt=\frac{du}{2\sqrt{2n+1}}$ and the limits of the integral will be: $0$ and $x+\sqrt{2n+1}$
so now we have:
$$L(n)=\frac{2^{2n-1}\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{x+\sqrt{2n+1}}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2n+1}}\frac{u^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}(2n+1)^{(n-1)/2}}\left(1-\frac{u}{2\sqrt{2n+1}}\right)^{n-1}du$$
$$=\frac{2^{n-1}\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\pi}(2n+1)^{(n+1)/2}}\int_0^{x+\sqrt{2n+1}}u^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{u}{2\sqrt{2n+1}}\right)^{n-1}du$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\pi}(2n+1)^n}\int_0^{x+\sqrt{2n+1}}u^{n-1}\left(2\sqrt{2n+1}-u\right)^{n-1}du$$
now its not looking particularly nice but I am going to try and split up the domain and see what happens: $v=u-\sqrt{2n+1},\,dv=du$
$$L(n)=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\pi}(2n+1)^n}\int_{-\sqrt{2n+1}}^x(v+\sqrt{2n+1})^{n-1}(\sqrt{2n+1}-v)^{n-1}dv$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\pi}(2n+1)^n}\int_{-\sqrt{2n+1}}^x\left(\sqrt{2n+1}-v^2\right)^{n-1}dv$$

---

If we look at the lower portion of this we have:
$$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\pi}(2n+1)^n}\int_{-\sqrt{2n+1}}^0\left(\sqrt{2n+1}-v^2\right)^{n-1}dv$$
looking at the integral at the boundaries we can see:
$$f(-\sqrt{2n+1})=(2n+1)^{(n-1)/2}\left(1-(2n+1)^{1/2}\right)^{n-1}$$
so as $n\to\infty$, $f(-\sqrt{2n+1})\approx (2n+1)^{n-1}$
and for the other boundary:
$$f(0)=(2n+1)^{(n-1)/2}$$
and we are integrating over a region of width $\sqrt{2n+1}$ we can use our minima our upper and lower bounds as the upper and lower bounds of the integral:
$$(2n+1)^{n/2}\le J\le (2n+1)^{n-1/2}$$ and now just put in the expression beforehand:
$$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\pi}(2n+1)^n}(2n+1)^{n/2}\le J_n\le \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\pi}(2n+1)^n}(2n+1)^{n-1/2}$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\pi}(2n+1)^{n/2}}\le J_n\le \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{2n+1}}$$
taking the limit we get:
$$0\le J_{\infty}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$
Now we are left with:
$$\int_0^x(\sqrt{2n+1}-v^2)^{n-1}dv\le L(n)\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}+\int_0^x(\sqrt{2n+1}-v^2)^{n-1}dv$$
and at this point I'm really struggling might take another look later :)